# Objective C Segues - Recursive Scenes

Tags: objective-c, recursion, storyboard, scene

I have a Storyboard with a tableview scene which displays a list of categories. These categories contain more sub-categories, and those even more. The problem is, the level of categories can potentially be infinite, but I can't really have an infinite number of scenes in the storyboard.

I have managed to bring it down to 2 scenes which references each other, but I need to know if there is a way to bring it down to one scene. In this specific project, this situation will occur at least another 7 times, and it will be quite troublesome to do everything twice every time there is a change.

Regards,
EZFrag

Comment: It sounds like you should be creating your table programmatically instead of with storyboard.

Comment: Well, I would argue that that line of thinking should be to make the segue programmatically, not the layout.

Comment: Yup, that would have been easier, but the storyboard is an explicit, non negotiable requirement >.< No part of the UI is allowed to be in the code.

Comment: @EZFrag I'm not saying lay out the UI, I'm saying populate your table programmatically. Instead of navigating to a new table, just change the datasource for your current one.

Comment: Oh, I get where you are going with this... That might actually work...